# google_endpoints_service.map: googleapi: Error 403: Caller does not have permission 'servicemanagement.services.create' on project , forbidden

Tags: google-cloud-robotics

I'm installing Google Cloud Robotics Core (https://github.com/googlecloudrobotics/core) but it allways gives me the following error when running ./deploy.sh create

---

Error: Error applying plan:

2 error(s) occurred:

- google_endpoints_service.map: 1 error(s) occurred:
- google_endpoints_service.map: googleapi: Error 403: Caller does not have permission 'servicemanagement.services.create' on project robotstest., forbidden
- google_compute_address.cloud_robotics: 1 error(s) occurred:
- google_compute_address.cloud_robotics: Error creating Address: googleapi: Error 403: Access Not Configured. Compute Engine API has not been used in project 933659281767 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/compute.googleapis.com/overview?project=933659281767 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry., accessNotConfigured

Terraform does not automatically rollback in the face of errors.
Instead, your Terraform state file has been partially updated with
any resources that successfully completed. Please address the error
above and apply again to incrementally change your infrastructure.

terraform apply failed

---

I have set the correct project with "./deploy.sh set-project robotstest" but that project id where the error refers is not my project so could there be some hardcoded setting somewhere in installer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the feedback! I have pushed [a change](https://github.com/googlecloudrobotics/core/commit/b1f50a04f9772dc7f087b555f9f9e886c2e917ea) which should fix the problem with `google_compute_address`. Could you pull the latest code and try again?

Regarding the error `google_endpoints_service`, are you using the same identity for `gcloud` as you did when you created the project? You can check by running `gcloud auth list` (the active account is the one with a `*`), and by going to the [IAM console](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam), checking that the `robotstest` project is selected at the top, and then looking for a line with "Owner" as the role. Does the member identity for the Owner match the active account in gcloud? If not, try rerunning `gcloud auth login`, or granting Owner permissions to the account you want to use.

Comment: Thanks it works now!
Although installer says that Appy complete etc. but finally prints out error:
INFO: Build completed successfully, 73 total actions
....
  File "/home/jhr/core/bazel-bin/src/go/cmd/setup-robot/setup-robot.push.runfiles/httplib2/__init__.py", line 988
    raise socket.error, msg
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Could you paste the whole output on e.g. https://gist.github.com/ and link here. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/lumikasa/cfaaf05d68fa028dae4eb95e50db4191 you can find there as much as there was in terminal history

Comment: Thanks for the extra info. I've filed https://github.com/googlecloudrobotics/core/issues/4
Which distro/version are you using? It looks like `python` points to `python3` - you could try the "Another way to force the use of python2" instructions here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/python#Python_2

Answer (score 0):

When creating a project on GCP it might assign you a different project-id to make it unique. You can check on https://console.cloud.google.com/home/dashboard on the `project info` card. Use the `Project ID` value in the `set-project` call.

If you did all this right, please let us know, then it is something else.

Comment: It is something else because I have done exactly that and triple checked that I'm using the same Project ID that I have in GCP and set it as parameter in set-project

Comment: Thanks for the update. Did you try to re-run ./deploy.sh create (or ./deploy.sh update). There might be a race in the terraform provider enabling some resources and not sufficiently waiting for them to be ready.

Comment: Yes I did tried to re-run and even made a new project and tried to do everything again several times. Still giving me 403:
---------
Error: Error applying plan:

2 error(s) occurred:

* google_endpoints_service.map: 1 error(s) occurred:

* google_endpoints_service.map: googleapi: Error 403: Project 'robots' not found or permission denied., forbidden
* google_compute_address.cloud_robotics: 1 error(s) occurred:

* google_compute_address.cloud_robotics: Error creating Address: googleapi: Error 404: Failed to find project robots, notFound
..........

Comment: Sorry that this is not going easy for you. Could you perhaps take a screenshot of the https://console.cloud.google.com/home/dashboard - especially the project info card?  Or run "gcloud projects list" and paste the outputs here.

Comment: I have there several projects but eq. this one I tried last, name: robots, Project ID: robots-232211, Project number: 527034362520